# FireBase query not working with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my database schema as you can see value "iCgvaKOFlncNtHtjwUpC759PHTX2" under users_relations->userID->pending->uid

I am building query like this

```
let userRelationsPendingRef = Database.database().reference().child("users_relations").child("QvKH90udoIU9C3lbjP9OjpA5DC22").child("pending")
        userRelationsPendingRef.queryEqual(toValue: "iCgvaKOFlncNtHtjwUpC759PHTX2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in
                    if snapShot.exists() {
                        completion(.pending)
                    }
    })
```

But it returns null in snapShot object. 
Any kind of help will be hight appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: I think you can try this: `userRelationsPendingRef.child("uid").queryEqual(toValue: "iCgvaKOFlncNtHtjwUpC759PHTX2").observeSingleEvent....`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As was stated in the comments, make sure your path is correct, and then querying should be fine. In the original post you never added the "uid", so the correct code would be the following:

```
let userRelationsPendingRef = Database.database().reference().child("users_relations").child("QvKH90udoIU9C3lbjP9OjpA5DC22").child("pending")
        userRelationsPendingRef.child("uid").queryEqual(toValue: "iCgvaKOFlncNtHtjwUpC759PHTX2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in
                    if snapShot.exists() {
                        completion(.pending)
                    }
    })
```